# An array inside Vue component has multiple reactiveSetter and reactiveGetter methods when logging in console

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs2, vue-component

I developed a vue chat component using Typescript. I have a messages array that is filled with *send* function and using it as a **Web Component** then using *vue-custom-element*.

The problem is that when I'm logging the *messages* array there is a bunch of *reactiveSetter* and *reactiveGetter* mothods there. Did I do something wrong?

[image: Console log with multiple reactiveSetter function]

This is the vue component:

```js
<template>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="room" class v-chat-scroll="{ always: false, smooth: true }">
      <div
        class="message"
        v-for="message in messages"
        :key="message.id"
        :class="message.owns ? 'owns' : ''"
      >
        <fa-icon icon="user" />
        <app-baloon :direction="message.owns ? 'right' : 'left'">
          <!-- <div class="baloon" > -->
          <strong>{{ message.user }}:</strong>
          {{ message.text }}
        </app-baloon>
        <!-- </div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <textarea
      type="text"
      v-model="newMessage"
      id="new-message"
      @keydown.enter.exact.prevent="send"
      placeholder="Send the message..."
    ></textarea>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";
import AppBaloon from "../AppBaloon";
import { log } from "fabric/fabric-impl";

interface Message {
  id: number;
  user: string;
  text: string;
  time: string;
  owns: boolean;
}

@Component({
  components: {
    AppBaloon
  }
})
export default class Chat extends Vue {
  private messages = [
    {
      id: 1,
      user: "John",
      text: "Hello",
      time: "10:52",
      owns: false
    }
  ] as Message[];
  newMessage = "";

  send() {
    if (this.newMessage.trim() != "") {
      const newMessageItem = {
        id: Math.random(),
        user: "Alice",
        text: this.newMessage,
        time: new Date().toJSON().slice(11, 16),
        owns: true
      } as Message;

      this.messages.push(newMessageItem);
    }
    this.newMessage = "";
    console.log(this.messages);
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When you pass a plain JavaScript object to a Vue instance as its data
> option, **Vue will walk through all of its properties and convert them
> to getter/setters using Object.defineProperty**. This is an ES5-only and
> un-shimmable feature, which is why Vue doesn’t support IE8 and below.

More: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#How-Changes-Are-Tracked

This means that no - there's no error, it's the main method **Vue** keeps data reactive. So it's a feature (or THE feature, if you like) :)

> One caveat is that browser consoles format getter/setters differently
> when converted data objects are logged, so you may want to install
> vue-devtools for a more inspection-friendly interface.

Vue devtools: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools